# Como escrever data e hora atual no selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Gostaria de saber como faço para incluir a data atual em formato PT/BR como no exemplo: 21/07/2021
e uma data especifica como por exemplo: 01/01/2020

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from datetime import datetime

navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_Periodo_drpPeriodo"]').click()
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="APeriodoDigitar"]').click()
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_Periodo_txtPeriodoDataInicial"]').(quero digitar aqui a data!)
```

Comment: Essa data vai vir de onde? Do `datetime` ?

Comment: `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")` ?